# Cannot POST /url with AngularJS & PHP Mailform

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, post

I'm trying to send email message through an AngularJS application with PHPMailer. Everytime I submit the form I am redirected to a blank page on url `http://192.168.1.38:3000/#/contact` saying

> CANNOT POST /

My contact form is in another html file `pages/contact.html` and the routing is

```
        .when('/contact', {
          templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
          controller  : 'ContactController'
        });
```

My contact form begins with

```
 <form ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

I'm wondering if I can not leave `action=""` blank on the form. But I've also tried putting `/#contact` and `/#/contact` but the same error always shows up.

When I am on the contact page the url is `http://192.168.1.38:3000/#/contact`

When submitting the form, the console spits out:

```
POST http://192.168.1.38:3000/ 404 (Not Found)
```

and network tab says:

```
Remote Address:192.168.1.38:3000
Request URL:http://192.168.1.38:3000/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
----------------------------------------------
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I do however receive the email that I send from the email form from the web application so it's only that I can get rid of this error. I've tried uploading my whole application onto a server but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you try to remove the action attr completely?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I can't believe that this was the solution. I removed the action attr and now it works like a charm ... what an odd thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `action=""` and the page will not attempt to redirect. If you do want to show a success page, place it in the `action=""`.